# Android support design Floating Action Button

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-support-design

I'm trying to decrease `FAB` margins on *pre-Lollipop* devices but whatever I do - nothing changes. I create two `FAB`s one is in the `right|end|bottom` other is up to the previous. That `16dp` margins make a distance between two `FAB`s for `32dp` and this is too large for me. If to use `bottop_padding` down button's clickable area overlapping the second button. Maybe, somebody had the same problem? Please, help me!

[here is picture of how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4bgb.jpg)

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/directions"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/uer_position"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/second"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/my_location"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: could you post your xml file?

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla, done

Comment: *That 16dp margins* which? Where are they defined?

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla, I don't think that it will help You because margins don't change in any way, even programmatically with viewTreeObservers.

Comment: @TimCastelijns nowhere. By the system I guess.  http://imgur.com/BTb9EDq here is how it looks like

Comment: @TimCastelijns, look at this image http://imgur.com/BTb9EDq . Whatever I do with margins and paddings that clickable area (which is selected in redactor) never disappears on pre-Lollipop devices

Answer (score 0):

On pre-lollipop, margins are automatically added to the `FAB`s. Create a new folder named `values-v21` and create a `xml` file named `dimes.xml` and add the following line

```
 <dimen name="btn_fab_margins">16dp</dimen>
```

Then go to your `dimens.xml` in your `values` folder and add the following

```
<dimen name="btn_fab_margins">0dp</dimen>
```

Now in your layout add following to the FABs

```
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/btn_fab_margins"
```

The problem will be solved. as with pre-lollipop it will take the `0dp` margin and with lollipop it take the `16dp` margin.

Comment: I've done like this but with using Styles. Nothing changes on pre-lollipop devices

Comment: Are you sure added dimensions to both value files?

Comment: Set margin to `0` dont deletes margins from screenshot,